# Clearing list in a loop

Tags: perl, list

I have a list of lines (about 2K) that I need to compare to much bigger list on certain criteria and save the results. So what I'm doing is:

```
foreach( keys %lines1 )
{
    ($orig1,$orig2,$orig3) = (split( /,/, $lines1{$_}))[1,2,3]
    push( @result, grep{ ($data1,$data2,$data3) = (split( /,/, $lines2{$_})[1,2,3];$orig1 == $data1 && $orig2 == $data2 && $orig3 == $data3 } keys %lines2 );
    $hash_result{$count} = @result;
}
```

Problem is `@result` accumulates data.
So on the first run it's size is 1, on the second the data is pushed and the size is 2: old line matched and new line matched.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, but don't remember what.

Both lists comes from the same file as CSV. They are different by one field.

Input:

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,0 - $line1
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,1 - $line2
```

There is couple of lines of type `$line1`.

Output:
In the output it probably should be a hash of list of list, The task is: for every `$line1` that have matches calculate some statistics.

Could someone please help?

Or maybe I'm doing it completely wrong?

[EDIT]

What I'm looking for here is something like this:

"$hash_result{$count} = [[1,2,3,10,4,6][1,2,3,5,3,11][1,2,3,100,60,20]]"

so that I can calculate some statistics on the $count line.

[/EDIT]

Comment: @mpapec, added explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Where `$count` comes from? `@result`, of course, accumulate data as you're pushing in it at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @M42, exactly. Do you know how to clear the list up? Problem is there might be multiple lines in %lines2 that correspond to %lines1. $count variable is just a counter that I use to keep track of the hash. AFAIK, I can't use "$hash_result{@result}", so I use "$count" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding calculation of average

```
foreach( keys %lines1 ) {
    ($orig1,$orig2,$orig3) = (split( /,/, $lines1{$_}))[1,2,3]
    @result = grep{ ($data1,$data2,$data3) = (split( /,/, $lines2{$_})[1,2,3];$orig1 == $data1 && $orig2 == $data2 && $orig3 == $data3 } keys %lines2 );
    push @{$hash_result{$count}}, [ @result ];
}
my $average= 0;
foreach my $list (@{$hash_result{$count}}) {
    $average+= $list->[3]; # 10 + 5 + 100
}
$average/= scalar(@{$hash_result{$count}});   # 10+5+100 / 3
```

Comment: Apparently I was too fast. As far as I understand "@result" will have a one flat list and not list of lists, right? Because what I'm looking for is this: $hash_result{$count} = [[1,2,3,10,4,6],[1,2,3,5,3,11],[1,2,3,100,60,20]]". This way I will be able to count some statistics on the resulting list of lists. But you code will produce $hash_result{$count}=[1,2,3,10,4,6,1,2,3,5,3,11,1,2,3,100,60,20]" Thank you.

Comment: `$hash_result{$count} = @result;` is same as `$hash_result{$count} = $#result+1;` How could `$hash_result{$count}` be an array?

Comment: @M42, and how can I access the data in the list? Meaning, I want to print [1,2,3,10,4,6] for the first element. Like I said, it's been a while, sorry. ;-) Also I think in this case I will have a list of hash of list, and not hash of list of list. I need to calculate some statistics: ( 10 + 5 + 100 ) / 3 = 115 / 3 = 38.33333, as an example.